how to convert windows filetime 64bit hex to date and time?
i have this reg_binary (5D-07-BB-CB-60-1F-D7-01) value of the shutdowntime from the registry how to convert it to this format (DDMMYYYY HH:MM:SS)? enter image description here
is there a simple way to do it? is there a website that can convert it?

PowerShell can do the trick:
[system.datetime]::FromFileTime(0x01d71f60cbbb075d).ToString('ddMMyyyy HH:mm:ss')

You need to reverse the bytes of your reg_binary, because it is a little-endian representation of the 64-bit FileTime value
